data base queries in application is running on the local environment, but not on microsoft azure?
i created a project which is using external mysql database , the application has node.js backend and react frontend i am using azure static web-app, and it is deployed on microsoft azure but according to my code it is giving query error
router.post("/adminlogin", (req, res) => {
    const sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email = ? AND password = ?";
    con.query(sql, [req.body.email, req.body.password], (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Query error:", err);
            return res.json({ loginStatus: false, Error: "Query error", Details: err.message });
        }
        if (result.length > 0) {
            const email = result[0].email;
            const token = jwt.sign(
                { role: "admin", email: email, id: result[0].id },
                "jwt_secret_key",
                { expiresIn: "1d" }
            );
            res.cookie('token', token);
            return res.json({ loginStatus: true });
        } else {
            return res.json({ loginStatus: false, Error: "Wrong email or password" });
        }
    });
});

i am using f1 shared free app services for my node js backend, why is it giving query error
the database queries in my node js backend should work on microsoft azure

Can you share the error message ? make sure the database server is accessible from the azure app service .  You should also share what have you done so far to troubleshoot the problem.

@rohit the error message is : {
"loginStatus": false,
"Error": "Query error",
"Details": "Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error."
}  : the server is fully working in local enivornment but not in microsoft azure, i am using external database , not from microsoft azure.

The error message does not give much info. Where is this external database located? Is it  on-premises? Does it allow connection from outside the network?

@rohit see, sometimes the api is working and sometimes its not,  on azure it is giving query error but in local environment the api is fully working without error, the database is freesqldatabase located outside the ms azure.

@NikhilSingh can you share your folder structure of the web app?? if possible repo

@VivekVaibhavShandilya https://github.com/nikhilkcodes/emp-backend

Static Web app only support Azure Function as Integrated backend. For reference check this MS Document,
To use Express or any other backend code, its need to be deployed in Azure App Services OR Azure Container Apps and need to be linked to static web App. For Reference Check this MS Document.
Link Azure App Service.
Link Azure Container Apps.
Link Azure API Management.
Below is my code to use Azure Function as backend. I am Using HTTP Trigger. Function code is inside Funcion folder. which is mention in API in yml file.
My Directory:

httpTrigger.js:
// const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
import { app } from "@azure/functions";
import mssql from "mssql";

app.http('data', {
    methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    authLevel: 'anonymous',
    handler: async (request, context) => {

        context.log(`Http function processed request for url "${request.url}"`);
        try{
            const config = {  
                server: 'dbserver5spe.database.windows.net',  //update me
                authentication: {
                    type: 'default',
                    options: {
                        userName: 'vivek', //update me
                        password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'  //update me
                    }
                },
                options: {
                    encrypt: true,
                    database: 'staticwebapp'  //update me
                }
            }; 
        
            await mssql.connect(config)
        
            const result = await mssql.query('SELECT SYSTEM_USER as username;');
            return {body: JSON.stringify(result.recordset)}
    }
    catch (error) {
        context.log.error('Database connection/query error:', error);
        return { body: 'Error connecting to the database', status: 500 };
    } finally {
        // Close the connection
        await mssql.close();
    }
}
})

App.jsx:
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';


function App() {
  const [data,setData] = useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
  fetch('http://localhost:7071/api/data')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data=>setData(data))
  },[])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        value: {data.map((item, index) => (
                  item.username
                ))}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

My Static web App github yml file
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_RED_PEBBLE_0C0BF510F }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/" # App source code path
          api_location: "./Function" # Api source code path - optional
          output_location: "dist" # Built app content directory - optional
          
  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_RED_PEBBLE_0C0BF510F }}
          action: "close"

OUTPUT:

React

Function backend

